# What exactly happens when a built-in command is run in a shell?

Tags: shell, shell-builtin, thread

I know that external commands are run in the shell by creating a separate process, but what exactly happens when a built-in command is run in a shell?

Are they executed as a function,  or does the shell create a new thread to execute them?

Comment: That's going to be shell-specific. And it probably varies depending on the command (and possibly how its used in a pipe).

Comment: okay for example if the shell is bash, and command is 'cd', so how is it implemented?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your concrete example, there is a function `cd_builtin`, which is defined in builtins/cd.def (in the bash source code). It normally does a `cd` by calling that function. But it may fork first if you use it in a pipeline—for example, `cd / | echo` forks and calls `cd_builtin` in the child. You can also notice this by how the directory doesn't actually change:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ cd /tmp/
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ cd / | echo -n
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ cd /
anthony@Zia:/$
```

Notice how the directory only changes when I don't pipe from `cd`.

Answer (score 7):

Built-in commands, by definition, are executed inside the main executable, as opposed to in a different program.

All shell commands are synchronous: the shell waits for the command to complete before it executes the next one. When running an external command, the shell has to create a separate process to run that command, and wait for it to exit. When running a built-in command, there is no need to create a new thread of execution: the command is executed inside the main thread.

I don't think any of the common shells use threads in their internal design. Shell capabilities are pretty tied with the traditional single-thread-per-process Unix model, there's no problem in shell design that threads would solve.

It's highly likely that every builtin is implemented by a function at some level in the shell's source code.

Answer (score 4):

I would think they run as a function within the space of the `bash` executable. There is a comment in the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) that states it as follows:

*excerpt*

> A builtin is a command contained within the Bash tool set, literally
>   built in. This is either for performance reasons -- builtins execute
>   faster than external commands, which usually require forking off [1](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) a
>   separate process -- or because a particular builtin needs direct
>   access to the shell internals.

Comment: but here we aren't creating a new process, we are creating a new thread whose execution is faster than creating a process. i agree that function implementation is faster than thread creation. But the scenario here is this for the execution time:   process creation>thread creation>function calling. We can't be sure whether it is thread or function

Comment: I think you're getting hung up on semantics. I'm pretty sure these are serviced by function calls by bash. My reasoning is that if I watch my bash process using a tool such as htop configured to show threads, there aren't any when I run the different built-in commands to bash.

Comment: okay thank you for the clarification, i will check it